# Customizing Finder like Windows File Explorer

Tags: finder

I am migrating from Windows to Mac OS X. I really like Windows file explorer. In the left panel, a tree of folders shows up, and in the right panel, files show up. In addition, I enjoy naming files very long such as `project1_year1_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A01.docx`,

and as I proceed I create:

```
`project1_year1_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A01.docx`
`project1_year1_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A02.docx`
`project1_year1_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A03.docx`
`project1_year2_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A01.docx`
`project1_year2_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A02.docx`
`project1_year2_this_project_is_about_something_ver_A03.docx`
```

In Mac OS X, it might look something like:

```
`project1_year.......docx`
`project1_year.......docx`
`project1_year.......docx`
`project1_year.......docx`
`project1_year.......docx`
`project1_year.......docx`
```

which is a total mess. I think I was able to adjust the column length, but I want to see long file names without adjusting it and when I save as a new file name inside software like MS Word.

Is there any workaround to make Finder look like what I want? (1) a tree of folders, and (2) long file names without showing any other file information column.

Comment: Since ur not on as primitive OS as windows, you no longer need to use "_", your a human, uses spaces like normal

Comment: And you also don't need to save separate versions like you showed in the example. Some apps have support for lion's versions feature, and all apps can "undo" beyond save points (much unlike windows)

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX Thanks for comments. Of course, I don't usually use "_" for filenames, but tend to use "_" for creating `.html`, `.php`, `.tex`, etc. In some cases, LaTeX or some other programming languages tend to have some troubles with spaces in filename. Also, controlling versions by creating multiple copies is my old habit, especially for sequential collaboration and creating backups and history.

Comment: time machine's hourly backups would suffice for "history" in the case of any files that don't support versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to List View.
- Control-click on the bar that says "Name  Date Modified  Size  " etc.
- Uncheck all the fields (Date modified, Size, Kind, etc.)

You should now have long filenames and expandable folders.

Comment: Thanks. Can I put the tree in the left and the file contents in the right?